# Can I change an extension method into a property?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does C# have extension properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619033/does-c-sharp-have-extension-properties)

I have the following:

```
 public static class EnumExt
    {
        public static string D2(this Enum key)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(key).ToString("D2");
        }
    }
```

Which I use like this:

```
PageType.ContentBlock.D2()
```

Where PageType is an Enum.

Is there a way I can do this so that D2 is a property and rather not a method? It doesn't seem to make much sense to me that I always have to put the () after D2 ?

Comment: I have looked for the answer to this and I found the answer to be no. I hope I'm wrong and there is a way.

Comment: No - you cannot. C# at this point in time will not support what you are asking for.

Comment: So you are asking this just because you cant be bothered to add the brackets? How you ever considered using VB.Net, you can save yourself quite a few characters with that! (facepalm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you've got a parameter : `this Enum key`

even if usage "looks like" a property, remind that

```
PageType.ContentBlock.D2();
```

is equivalent to

```
EnumExt.D2(PageType.ContentBlock);
```

so, when you need a parameter, use... a method !

[Does C# have extension properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619033/does-c-sharp-have-extension-properties)

Answer (score 1):

No, that's why it is called Extension *Method*. While it may look like it could be converted to a property if no other parameters are expected (as in `var x = y.ExtensionMethod();`), an extension method can take additional parameters. Example:

```
int y = x.Add(3);

public static int Add(this int source, int value)
{
    return source + value;
}
```

Also, extension methods are just "syntactic sugar". The compiler translates them into a normal method call with the source object being passed as parameter.

Example (extension methods are in a class `ExtensionMethods`):

```
int y = x.Add(3);
```

will be converted to

```
int y = ExtensionMethods.Add(x, 3);
```

by the compiler.