# EF Core - How to find maximum length if available for the given table and property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am looking for a way to find the maximum length if available for the given table and property using EF Core.

I can see the solution is available in EF using IObjectContextAdapter, however it is not available in EF Core.

Kind Regards

Comment: The [answer(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957517/how-to-adapt-iobjectcontextadapter-from-ef-6-to-ef-core) this question might help.

Comment: Things like this are rarely dynamic.   EF migrations are targeted at a particular server type (MS-SQL is different to MySql or Cosmos), so you aren't going to be able to deploy to a server you aren't expecting, therefore you will probably already know what the maximum is.