# Is it appropriate to have multiple identical classes with different names?

Tags: c#, inheritance, nomenclature

I have a question about naming multiple classes that share similar functionality. I am working on a scientific API and have the following classes/interfaces:

```
public interface IRange<T>{
    T Minimum {get;}
    T Maximum {get;}
    // A few other methods that aren't important
}

public class Range<T> : IRange<T> where T: IComparable<T> {
    public T Minimum {get; protected set;}
    public T Maximum {get; protected set;}

    public Range(T minimum, T maximum) {
        Minimum = minimum;
        Maximum = maximum;
    }
}
```

For my API, I work with `double` ranges a lot (i.e., `Range<double>`), so I made an another class called `MassRange`. This class also has a few new constructors and properties shown below:

```
public class MassRange : Range<double>, IRange<double> {
    public double Width { get { return Maximum - Minimum;} }
    public double Mean { get { return (Maximum + Minimum) / 2.0;} }

    public MassRange(double mean, MassTolerance width) {
        Minimum = mean - width.Value;  // pseudo-code
        Maximum = mean + width.Value;
    }
}
```

Conceptually, I also have another type of `Range<double>` called a `MzRange`, that shares all the same structure and functionality as `MassRange` but I want to keep separate in the API. They act exactly the same and store the same types of data, but in terms of the science, they are different and distinct.

So I considered renaming the `MassRange` class to a more generic name of `DoubleRange` and then have both `MassRange : DoubleRange` and `MzRange : DoubleRange` designed like so:

```
public MzRange : DoubleRange, IRange<double> {}

public MassRange : DoubleRange, IRange<double> {}
```

But I don't really care for the name `DoubleRange`, and would rather not expose it publicly through my API. Is exposing two distinct types with the same functionality even appropriate? Should I just come up with a better name for `DoubleRange` and forgo `MzRange` and `MassRange`? Can I make `DoubleRange` internal or something so that it is not exposed through the API but can still be used?

This seems to be a case for [Extension Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619033/does-c-sharp-have-extension-properties) but I know they don't currently exist.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any reason you can't accomplish this with standard [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static double GetWidth(this IRange<double> range) {
    return range.Maximum - range.Minimum;
}

public static double GetMean(this IRange<double> range) {
    return (range.Maximum + range.Minimum) / 2.0;
}
```

And then you can call it from any implementation of `IRange`:

```
var massRange = ...
var mean = massRange.GetMean();
```

I know it may not have the syntactic appeal of extension properties, but it's a clean solution that gets around having to create that `DoubleRange` class.

Comment: I definitely agree with what you're saying here. They should implement  their needs in the way that Linq is implemented. A lot of generic interfaces and a lot of extension methods. +1

Comment: This works for the properties, but does not help with the new constructor I added to DoubleRange.

Comment: @Moop It wouldn't provide you any constructors, but presumably you'd have different constructors on the `MassRange` and `MzRange` class that your `DoubleRange` wouldn't have anyway, right? Does `MzRange` take an `MzTolerance`? Of course you can create a static factory method depending on your exact needs, but it's not entirely clear from the question exactly what that would be.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely appropriate. Besides the logical distinction, it gives you the possibility to evolve the two classes independently from each other in future.

Even if elephants and birds are animals (both inherit from animals) and both have the same set of properties (they don't add or override members), you might want to add a `Fly` method to birds in future. *I assume that elephants named [Dumbo](http://www.google.ch/search?q=dumbo%20flying&tbm=isch) do not exist in real world scenarios :-)*

Comment: Why wouldn't you have an `Animal` class where `Elephant` and `Bird` inherit from it? The `Bird` and `Elephant` classes are then not identical, but rather they are both inheriting from `Animal` which contains base property like `Weight` or `Height` or some common property for all animals. You wouldn't want to make a `Bird` and `Elephant` with duplicate properties all over the place; that would be a poor design.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray I can see what Oliver is saying, but I suppose `Elephant` and `Bird` may not be the best metaphor here. `Elephant` and `Car` may be better. Both have a certain weight and height, and the both even have a trunk. However, they are so different, it might warrant designing completely different hierarchies. Still, I'd probably design functional interfaces around them (e.g. `Car : IHasWheels`) to describe what you can actually *do* with them.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray: By "elephants and birds are animals" I mean that both inherit from `animal`. And by "both have the same set of properties" I mean that they do not provide additional members besides what they inherit from `animal`.

Comment: It is fine to create a Bird and Elephant classes, make them inherit from Animal, and keep it there. It isn't to have both classes inherit Animal, then have them separately implement the exact same functionality.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I agree functional interfaces at that point would be beneficial. Thanks for giving that example, it made more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Having two types with the exact same functionality isn't appropriate as any change made to one type will need to be made to the other.

Unless you **know** that `MassRange` and `MzRange` will be differentiated at some point in the future, providing a better name for `DoubleRange` and forgoing `MassRange`/`MzRange` is the way to go. And even then, any shared functionality would need to be put in a parent type.

You can always provide some [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) to help users. For instance, you could create "dumb" classes called `MassRange` and `MzRange`, which simply extend `DoubleRange`. I'd keep the original, well named class exposed, to encourage users to use it, but if you really want to hide it, just use the `protected` accessor instead of `public`.