# How do I create an extension property in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to extend a property to a class such as 'string class'.

e.g.:

```
    public Color TextColor
    {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }

    string name="reza";
    name.TextColor;
    or
    name.TextColor= Color.Red;
```

Comment: Extension properties are not supported at this time.  Only extension methods.  More info [here](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/541454).

Comment: @DStanley They are supported in WPF via [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). To the OP, because you are talking about text color, is this for WPF or something else?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, not really.  That's just a XAML concept.  In VB or C# code you can't access the attached property as though it was a member of the target object.  You can't write C# code that looks anything like what the OP has suggested.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does C# have extension properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619033/does-c-sharp-have-extension-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot (at the time of writing) extend properties in c#, and you certainly cannot extend `string` seeing as it is a sealed class.
Use methods instead of properties, and make a `StringExtension` class instead of inheriting string.