# Xamarin NSIndexPath Extension / More than 2 items in path

Tags: c#, ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, nsindexpath

I currently am working on a project which has a `UICollectionView`, what I would like to do is to have another "Path" on the `NSIndexPath`, so that I can find an item.  Essentially I currently have:

A Section (which contains an individual)
A Row (which is essentially a "Day") this has multiple events in for an individuals day.- this is where i would like an extra index on my index path!)

But whenever I try to add an additional index on it complains that I can't have more than 2 indexes in my index path.  (However it does say I could use a "Category"  - therefore is there away I can do this in `Xamarin` / `C#` or am I out of luck?

Comment: Are you able to post any code with what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What does your data source look like? Is it: Section[Row[Item]]? Where Section is a List of Lists, Row is a List and Item is the individual Item?

Comment: It looks like a list of lists... so... a section would be a list of people, then within that is a list of days, then a list of what work they are doing on that day....

Answer (score 0):

[Category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html)s in Objective-C is like an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb383977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in C#.

You cant add a new property with extension methods see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619033/does-c-sharp-have-extension-properties) but you could do this add another NSIndexPath property to your collectionView cell class.

Comment: How do you mean add another NSIndexPath property to collectionView cell, (sorry my brain is a little fried today)